# CSS list within div positioning issue

Tags: css, css-float

I'm updating the page for my company site. The footer here: applebees.com works correctly, but I ported the code to my WHMCS template and it's positioning the sitemap incorrectly. Any ideas what's going on? http://applebees.com/clients

```
<footer class="row1">
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="row1">
      <div class="span2">
        <h3>Sitemap</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https://wwww.applebees.com/" title="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="clients/cart.php?gid=1" title="">Pricing</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="span2">
        <br><br>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="mailto:sales@applebees.com" title="">Reseller</a></li>
          <li><a href="mailto:sales@applebees.com" title="">Dedicated</a></li>
          <li><a href="https:clients/clientarea.php" title="">Support</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="span2">
        <br><br>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="https:assets/legal" title="">Terms Of Service</a></li>     
          <li><a href="https:assets/privacy" title="">Privacy Policy</a></li>           
          <!--<li><a href="#" title="">#</a></li>-->
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
        <h3>Contact</h3>
        <address>
    <strong>applebees, LLC</strong><br>
    San Francisco, CA<br>
    Los Angeles, CA<br>
    sales@applebees.com<br>
  </address>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /row -->    
  </div> <!-- /container -->
</footer>
```

CSS file for above page here: site/clients/templates/default/css/whmcs.css

The index.html page CSS (can't post hyperlinks): site/assets/css/style.min.css

I'm confused because I ported the code correctly, I think the divs are messing it up somehow?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the "noise" class gives some height of your div in armorshark.com. When you ported the region, you did not get the "noise" classed div. You can solve the with add the `height:` attribute on row1 class.